# Задача обработка ошибок на питоне

Tags: python, исключения

Прохожу Пайтон, задали задачу на обработку ошибок. Не могу сообразить, как написать код.

Создайте функцию `image_info` с 1 параметром типа `dict`. Функция ожидает словарь, в к-ом должно быть как минимум 2 ключа: `image_id`, `image_title`. Функция должна возвращать строку такого вида: `"image 'my cat' has id 5136"` (`my cat` и `id` будут зависеть от ключей). Если хотя бы одного из этих ключей в словаре нет, функция должна генерировать ошибку `TypeError`. Вызовите функцию и корректно обработайте ошибку в случае возникновения.

Мой код:

```
def fn(image_info: dict):
     try:
        title = image_info['image_title']
        image_id = image_info['image_id']
     except KeyError:
        return "Image'my cat' has id 5136"
     return f'image {title} has id {image_id}'
```

Comment: В блоке except вам нужно генерировать ошибку, а не возвращать строку из примера. Генерировать ошибку - значит через raise вызывать новую ошибку, `raise TypeError`, например. Ну и вызывающий код нужно добавить, где вы эту ошибку отловите и обработаете.

Answer (score 2):

```
def fn(image_info: dict):
    try:
        return f"Image '{image_info['image_title']}' has id {image_info['image_id']}"
    except KeyError as e:
        raise TypeError(e)

try:
    s = fn({'': 'my cat', 'image_id': 5136})
except TypeError as e:
    print(e.__class__.__name__, e.__doc__, e.args)
    s = fn({'image_title': 'my cat', 'image_id': 5136})
print(s)
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
def image_info(info: dict):
    try:
        return f"image '{info['image_title']}' has id {info['image_id']}"
    except KeyError as e:
        raise TypeError from None  # генерируем *только* TypeError

print(image_info({'image_title': 'my cat', 'image_id': '5136'}))
print(image_info({}))
```

Без конструкции `from None` в строке

```py
        raise TypeError from None
        #               ^^^^^^^^^
```

выполнение программы выглядело бы так:

```py
image 'my cat' has id 5136  # Всё OK
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
KeyError: 'image_title'  # Сначала вызывается KeyError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
TypeError  # А затем TypeError
```

А с ней вызывается *только* `TypeError`:

```
image 'my cat' has id 5136
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
TypeError  # Только TypeError
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def function(foo):
    print(foo)

def fn(image_info: dict):
    try:
        return f"{'Image'} {image_info ['image_title']} {'has id'} {image_info ['image_id']}"
    except Exception as e:
        raise TypeError(f"{'not key'} {e}")

dict_win = {
    'image_title': 'my cat',
    'image_id': 5136
}

dict_one = {
    'image_title': 'my cat',
}

dict_two = {
    'image_id': 5136
}

try:
    print(fn(dict_win))
except TypeError as w:
    print(w)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Не пользуясь отловом exception в функции. Как то так можно получить конкретные ключи которые отсутствуют.

```
req_keys = ['image_title', 'image_id']

def fn(image_info: dict):
    if all(rq_check_list:=[key in req_keys for key in image_info.keys()]):
        return f"Image '{image_info['image_title']}' has id {image_info['image_id']}"
    else:
        raise TypeError(f"rq key/keys {[req_keys[idx] for idx, item in enumerate(rq_check_list) if item]} does not exist..")

try:
    s = fn({'': 'my cat', 'image_id': 5136})
except TypeError as e:
    print(e)
```

Вывод в случае отсутствия.

```
rq key/keys ['image_id'] does not exist..
```

Обратите внимание, что вызов exception под неподходящий тип ошибки - негативно сказывается на семантике и общей читабельности кода. Пишите семантически правильно. Нужно проверить ключи в какой либо структуре отличной от стандартных(и если идёте через путь exception) - рейзите обычный `KeyError`. Не стоит вписывать в exception's свои понятия.

В тривиальных случаях совершайте перехваты встроенными.

Answer (score 0):

```
def image_info(info_dict):
    try:
        
        if 'image_id' not in info_dict or 'image_title' not in info_dict:
            raise KeyError("The dictionary must contain 'image_id' and 'image_title' keys.")

        
        result_str = f"image '{info_dict['image_title']}' has id {info_dict['image_id']}"
        return result_str
    except KeyError as e:
        
        raise TypeError(f"Error: {e}")



try:
  
    info_dict_1 = {'image_id': 5136, 'image_title': 'my cat'}

   
    result = image_info(info_dict_1)
    print(result)
except TypeError as e:
    
    print(f"Caught TypeError: {e}")
except Exception as ex_1:
  
    print(f"Caught Exception: {ex_1}")

try:
    
    info_dict_222 = {'image_id': 5136}


    result_33 = image_info(info_dict_222)
    print(result_33)
except TypeError as f:
    
    print(f"Caught TypeError: {f}")
except Exception as d:
   
    print(f"Caught Exception: {d}")
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
def image_info(image_dict):
    if 'image_id' not in image_dict:
        raise TypeError("Missing key 'image_id'")
    if 'image_title' not in image_dict:
        raise TypeError("Missing key 'image_title'")
    return print(f"Image {image_dict['image_title']} has id {image_dict['image_id']} !")


random_dict = {'image_title': 'my cat', 'image_id': 4411}

try:
    image_info(random_dict)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Дайте пояснение к своему варианту решения. Просто листинг кода не является хорошим вариантом ответа.